# Sudden 50% accuracy drop while training convolutional NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Training convolutional neural network from scratch on my own dataset with Keras and Tensorflow.

`learning rate = 0.0001`, 
5 classes to sort, 
no Dropout used,
dataset checked twice, no wrong labels found

Model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=(75,75,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(5,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.adam(lr=0.0001),
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              epochs=50,
                              validation_data=val_generator,
                              validation_steps=25)
```

Everytime when model achieves 25-35 epochs (80-90% accuracy) this happens:

```
Epoch 31/50
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3524 - acc: 0.8558 - val_loss: 0.4151 - val_acc: 0.7992
Epoch 32/50
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3393 - acc: 0.8700 - val_loss: 0.4384 - val_acc: 0.7951
Epoch 33/50
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3321 - acc: 0.8702 - val_loss: 0.4993 - val_acc: 0.7620
Epoch 34/50
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 33ms/step - loss: 1.5444 - acc: 0.3302 - val_loss: 1.6062 - val_acc: 0.1704
Epoch 35/50
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 1.6094 - acc: 0.2935 - val_loss: 1.6062 - val_acc: 0.1724
```

There is some similar problems with answers, but mostly they recommend to lower learning rate, but it doesnt help at all.

[image: Accuracy Drop]

UPD: almost all weights and biases in network became `nan`. Network somehow died inside

Comment: Any `nan` value in your datasets?

Comment: What loss/cost function do you use? Is there any specific reason to use `sigmoid` activation for the last dense layer?

Comment: What is the number of train and validation samples? Do you use the whole validation data everytime you calculate the accuracy?

Comment: Do you normalize your data? If not, what is the range of values?

Comment: Dataset is clear, no 'nan' values detected. Loss function - 'categorical_crossentropy'. No specific reason to use 'sigmoid'. 1157 train examples, 758 validation examples. Rescaling image values from range '[0,255]' to range '[0,1]'

Comment: Is this a *multi-label* problem (samples can belong to more than one class at the same time) or simply multi-class (5 non-overlapping classes)? If it is the second, you should definitely change your last activation to `softmax)`.

Comment: The downfall seems to be because of sigmoid function the last layer. You should use a softmax activation function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in this case:

I changed `sigmoid` function in last layer to `softmax` function and drops are gone

Why this worked out?

`sigmoid` activation function is used for binary (two-class) classifications.
In multiclassification problems we should use `softmax` function - special extension of `sigmoid` function for multiclassification problems.

More information: [Sigmoid vs Softmax](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier)

Special thanks to @desertnaut and @Shubham Panchal for error indication